# how to print the information in file descriptor in C.

Tags: c, printf, fopen

```
(gdb) print* data_out_file[0]
$1 = {_flags = -1, _IO_read_ptr = 0xffffffffffffffff <Address 0xffffffffffffffff out of bounds>, 
  _IO_read_end = 0xffffffffffffffff <Address 0xffffffffffffffff out of bounds>, 
  _IO_read_base = 0xffffffffffffffff <Address 0xffffffffffffffff out of bounds>, 
  _IO_write_base = 0xffffffffffffffff <Address 0xffffffffffffffff out of bounds>, 
  _IO_write_ptr = 0xffffffffffffffff <Address 0xffffffffffffffff out of bounds>, 
  _IO_write_end = 0xffffffffffffffff <Address 0xffffffffffffffff out of bounds>, 
  _IO_buf_base = 0xffffffffffffffff <Address 0xffffffffffffffff out of bounds>, 
  _IO_buf_end = 0xffffffffffffffff <Address 0xffffffffffffffff out of bounds>, 
  _IO_save_base = 0xffffffffffffffff <Address 0xffffffffffffffff out of bounds>, 
  _IO_backup_base = 0xffffffffffffffff <Address 0xffffffffffffffff out of bounds>, 
  _IO_save_end = 0xffffffffffffffff <Address 0xffffffffffffffff out of bounds>, _markers = 0xffffffffffffffff, _chain = 0x11004147ffffffff, 
  _fileno = 498074112, _flags2 = 12648704, _old_offset = 135392766359363840, _cur_column = 240, _vtable_offset = 66 'B', _shortbuf = "á", 
  _lock = 0xecfc392019202004, _offset = -35, __pad1 = 0xffffffffffffffff, __pad2 = 0xffffffffffffffff, __pad3 = 0xffffffffffffffff, 
  __pad4 = 0xffffffffffffffff, __pad5 = 18446744073709551615, _mode = -1, _unused2 = 'ÿ' <repeats 20 times>}
```

in GDB if we print the file pointer we get the descriptor.
just wondering how do we do it in C code like printf ?

Comment: A file descriptor is an integer. I don't know what _that_ is, because you haven't shown the declaration, or the type, or ... anything but a collection of invalid pointers, but it isn't a file descriptor.

Comment: If you are trying to find out a magic format specifier that prints all information, you are on the wrong way. Otherwise you can print each member with the correct format.

Comment: This is not a filedescriptor, but a *dereferenced* FILE pointer. And the `_fileno = 498074112` contains the underlying file descriptor. (but the whole structure contents look invalid to me)

Comment: You don't print a FILE* descriptor, it's a pointer to opaque data that is totally implementation dependent.

Comment: Under Linux, You need to print the individual members of the file descriptor.
For e.g. you have a file pointer `FILE *fp` to print the `_flag` use `fp->_flag`.

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my life

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want the `int` *file descriptor* value associated with a valid `FILE *` stream object, you use [the `fileno()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fileno.html):

> **NAME**
>
> fileno - map a stream pointer to a file descriptor
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int fileno(FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `fileno()` function shall return the integer file descriptor
>   associated with the `stream` pointed to by `stream`.
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> Upon successful completion, `fileno()` shall return the integer value
>   of the file descriptor associated with `stream`. Otherwise, the value
>   -1 shall be returned and `errno` set to indicate the error.

You do *not* dereference the `FILE *` stream object itself.  Doing so results in fragile, non-portable code that's prone to breakage.  On some implementations, the `FILE *` structure simply can *not* be dereferenced.